# While loop never ends despite condition is confirmed

Tags: loops, while-loop

I've a problem with a while loop.
I've defined a global flag in this way:

```
bool data_read_rdy = false;
```

in my interrupt this value change from false to true in this way

```
data_read_rdy = true;
```

I've a function that wait untill data_read_rdy becomes true, then set this value again to false and exit.

```
void function(void)
{   
    while(!data_read_rdy);

    data_read_rdy = false;      
}
```

My problem is that, if I debug step by step this works well. But if let code run it blocks in this while loop function and never exit although the value of data_read_rdy is true. Why that?

Comment: What does your loop do? I can only see a condition.

Comment: Sounds like you need to learn about `volatile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved declaring flag:

```
bool data_read_rdy = false;
```

to volatile as:

```
volatile bool data_read_rdy = false;
```

Problem was that compiler optimize code checking while loop condition only one time when maybe my interrupt wasn't asserted yet. Setting volatile it'll check condition until it verifies and then exit from loop.